# Extract top 5 values from a dataframe to plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following data:

```
Date
01/23/2020    55
03/01/2020    44
02/24/2020    39
03/12/2020    39
01/24/2020    39
02/05/2020    38
03/17/2020    37
03/16/2020    37
03/19/2020    37
03/14/2020    35
```

from `df.groupby(['Date']).count()['NN'].sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)`

I would like to extract the top 5 Dates in order to automatically include in this code:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,7))
df.groupby(['Date']).count()['NN'].plot(ax=ax)

xcoords = ["01/23/2020", "03/01/2020", "02/24/2020","03/12/2020","01/24/2020"]
for xc in xcoords:
    plt.axvline(x=xc, color='r')
```

At the moment the vertical lines are added based on the values that I change manually in xcoords. I would like to substitute there the top 5 `Date` values from `df.groupby(['Date']).count()['NN'].sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)` . How can I do?

Comment: `df.groupby(['Date']).count()['NN'].sort_values(ascending=False).head()` ?

Comment: should I include it in xcoord?